# manage Windows users with AD LDS

Tags: windows, ad-lds

I have a Windows 2008R2 server with about 30 users, which log in with remote desktop to use some application installed on the server itself

I would move the users from local users to AD LDS, so I can can better manage it, and also replicate to another (twin) server

Is this possible? Can anyone give me some reference? Or I'm trying to use the wrong tool?

I tried to follow some articles on the Microsoft KB, I installed teh service but I was not ablo to log in to the server using the new created user

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Active Directory, not LDS.

To be able to perform an interactive logon to a domain with a user account from a computer, there needs to be a domain, and that computer must be a member of the domain or a member of a domain that is trusted by the account domain.  In LDS, there isn't a domain or any domain controllers.  Your computer will be unable to take your user's credentials and authenticate on their behalf, due to LDS does not include directory services for the Windows operating system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Purpose**

Microsoft Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) is an independent mode of Active Directory that provides dedicated directory services **for applications.**  ☚